# $\lim_{t \to 1^{-}} (t^{p-q} -1) \log(1 -t)$

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

In evalataing $\Gamma'(p/q)/\Gamma(p/q)$f for $p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$ I encounter the following limit for use of Abel's Theorem :

$\lim_{t \to 1^{-}} (t^{p-q} -1) \log(1 -t) $ where $0 < p < q$;

The answer should be zero but no matter what method I use I fail : L'Hopital, log expansion, exponentiation of inside limit, etc.

How the limit can be evaluated?

Comment: What we know about $p-q$?

Comment: @zkutch, thanks I edited

Comment: Are q and p integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ (t^{p-q} -1) \ln(1 -t) \sim (p-q)\ln t \ln(1 -t)$$ and then twice L'Hopital with respect to $\frac{\ln(1 -t)}{\frac{1}{\ln t}}$ gives zero.

Comment: How do you infer $\lim (t^{p-q} -1) = \lim (p-q)\ln t$ for $t \to 1^-$ ?

Comment: We have $\frac{e^x-1}{x}\to 1$, when $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s= 1-t$. Then $$\lim_{t\to 1^-} (t^a-1)\log(1-t)=\lim_{s\to 0^+}((1-s)^a-1)\log s = \lim_{s\to 0^+}O(s \log s) = 0$$

Here we used that by the binomial series $(1-s)^a = 1+O(s)$.

Comment: May be you are trying to use the explicit binomial series $(1+x)^a = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{a}{k} x^k$, but one only needs the first three terms: $(1+x)^a = 1+a x +O(x^2)$. Actually, now that I think about it, two terms are enough.

Comment: @AdamRubinson What do you think now?

Comment: Yes this makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$(t^{p-q} -1) \log(1 -t)=\frac{1-t^{q-p}}{t^{q-p}} \log(1 -t) \to 0$$

since

$$1-t^{q-p}=(1-t)P(t)$$

and

$$(1-t)\log(1 -t)\to 0$$